# How to use python matplotlib code on website?

Tags: python, html, matplotlib

I've written a python program that uses features from the matplotlib library and I have a github website that I want to upload the file to so that people who visit the site can use the program. Any advice on how to do this? Do I need to use django or flask or something?

Comment: Repl.it has an embed function: https://docs.repl.it/repls/embed. Just create a repl with your code, then include the iframe in your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Repl.it has an embed function: https://docs.repl.it/repls/embed. Just create a repl with your code, then include the iframe in your website.

Extending on my comment, if you go to [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/python3), add your code and dependencies, and save the file, all you have to do is add the repl url as the src.parameter in this iframe:

```
<iframe 
    frameborder="0" 
    width="100%" 
    height="500px"         
    src="YOUR_REPL_URL"
></iframe>
```

and you can add it to your website.

Also, repl.it supports [interactive python plots](https://docs.repl.it/repls/python-plots)

Here's a demo of a matplotlib repl:

```
<iframe 
    frameborder="0" 
    width="100%" 
    height="500px"         
    src="https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/AwesomeSimplisticDictionaries?lite=true"
></iframe>
```

You can also add the `outputonly=1` param to the repl url to hide the editor.

This is how the output looks when you run the above repl:

[image: matplotlib]

More here: [docs.repl.it/repls/embed](https://docs.repl.it/repls/embed)

Apart from this, [trinket](https://trinket.io) is another alternative to repl.it that's worth looking into. **It only returns an image.**

Comment: This works however changing the orientation of the camera for the 3D plot is rather slow. Could this just be because the program is graphing a 3D object?

Comment: That sounds plausible if your 3D object is complex. Is it like that when you run it on desktop or just when run online? It's makes sense that since this runs in the browser it would be slower than if it ran directly on the desktop. There might not be anything you can do about this. You can also check out [trinket](https://trinket.io/python), another alternative to repl.it. Maybe it'll be faster, but, honestly, I like repl.it better, because it has more features, so if they're both run the same, I'd choose repl.it

Comment: Thanks for suggesting trinket. It only returns a image of the 3D object but that is fine for my purposes as moving the image isn't super crucial. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Good day!